# reading memory byte by byte

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I've got a long[] which I'd like to read two bits at a time. My data are the binary numbers 00,01,10, and 11 concatenated end to end, stuffed in a long, and then stuffed in an array.

I'll be reading a long stretch of this data at once, possibly starting halfway through, and it seems like it would make more sense to read straight from memory, two bytes at a time, rather than iterating through the long[] and pulling two bits at a time with a mask.

I can't seem to figure out how I'd go about this, and I've never been great with directly accessing memory (since I was brought up on java).

I've tried instantiating an array

```
unsigned long t[5];
t[0] = 4294967295;
t[1] = 0;
t[2] = 4294967294;
t[3] = 4294967296;
t[4] = 1;
```

and then printing `*(&t)` and `*(&t+1)`, but the plus one of course knows that it's the size of long and goes adds the appropriate value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pointer to a byte-sized data type. Try this:

```
unsigned char* p = (char *)t;
```

And use *p* pointer.

Comment: unsigned char would be a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always cast a pointer to char*, to get it byte by byte, if you also need to actually read it 2-bytes at a time, you'll need to use & and a proper bitmask (i.e. 0x3 to get the lowermost 2 bits). If you want, you can always just shift this mask with the << or >> operators to match further up or down in your current byte.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `std::vector<bool>` instead of a `long[]` for this. Retrieving the `i`'th 2-bit block can be done using

```
(int(v[i*2]) << 1) | v[i*2+1]
```

Comment: I'm actually going to end up using this since I really like the eloquence of this solution. However, I'm marking the other answer correct since it was closer a solution along the lines of how my question was worded. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple arithmetic:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
{
     for (unsigned int k = 0; k != CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned long int); k += 2)
     {
         std::printf("%02X ", n % 3);  // print last two bits
         n /= 4;                       // move down by two bits
     }
}
```

Instead of `5` you can of course say `sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0])`, if that's an option, or you can use iterators `std::begin(t)`/`std::end(t)`.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the array to `unsigned char *` and print that. The first two bytes (endianness aside) would then be:

```
((unsigned char *)t)[0]
((unsigned char *)t)[1]
```

...and so on

*Edit:* incidentally, `t` automatically decays to a pointer on its own, there's no need to do `&t`, you're just confusing yourself further.